# Get ImageNet label for a specific index in the 1000-dimensional output tensor in torch

Tags: label, torch, data-science, resnet, imagenet

I have the output Tensor of a forward pass for [a Facebook implementation of the ResNet model](https://github.com/facebook/fb.resnet.torch) with a cat image. That is a 1000-dimensional Tensor with the classification probabilities. Using [torch.topk](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/03c04c6/doc/maths.md#torchtopkresval-resind-x-k-dim-dir-sort) I can obtain the top-5 probabilities and their indexes in the output tensor. Now I want to see the human-readable labels for those most-probable indexes.

I searched online for the list of labels (which apparently are also called sysnets) and only found this: 
http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2015/browse-synsets

I put those labels in a file using line numbers as the label index and when I run the network with two different cat images, I get "screwdriver" as the top guess for both. If I sort the label file alphabetically, I get "cinema" for both.

This appears to be a problem with converting index to label, right?
So...the question is:
**How can I properly map index in network output tensor to Imagenet label?**

Comment: this would be a good question to ask on the github issues of the repository

Answer (score 2):

Found [this tutorial on training ConvNets on ImageNet by Dato](https://dato.com/learn/gallery/notebooks/build_imagenet_deeplearning.html) and at the end it contains the correct mapping. Reporting it here for the record:

```
{
 0: 'tench, Tinca tinca',
 1: 'goldfish, Carassius auratus',
 2: 'great white shark, white shark, man-eater, man-eating shark, Carcharodon carcharias',
 3: 'tiger shark, Galeocerdo cuvieri',
 4: 'hammerhead, hammerhead shark',
 5: 'electric ray, crampfish, numbfish, torpedo',
 6: 'stingray',
 7: 'cock',
 8: 'hen',
 9: 'ostrich, Struthio camelus',
 10: 'brambling, Fringilla montifringilla',
 ... [truncated for space]
 990: 'buckeye, horse chestnut, conker',
 991: 'coral fungus',
 992: 'agaric',
 993: 'gyromitra',
 994: 'stinkhorn, carrion fungus',
 995: 'earthstar',
 996: 'hen-of-the-woods, hen of the woods, Polyporus frondosus, Grifola frondosa',
 997: 'bolete',
 998: 'ear, spike, capitulum',
 999: 'toilet tissue, toilet paper, bathroom tissue'
}
```

Full mapping here: https://gist.github.com/maraoz/388eddec39d60c6d52d4