# ImageNet index to Wordnet 3.0 synsets

Tags: wordnet, imagenet

Working with ImageNet Resnet-50 in Caffe the prediction gives a 1000-dimensional vector. Is there an easy way to translate the indices of this vector to Wordnet 3.0 synset identifiers? For instance, that the 415: 'bakery, bakeshop, bakehouse' is "n02776631"?

I note that a similar question, [Get ImageNet label for a specific index in the 1000-dimensional output tensor in torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528905/get-imagenet-label-for-a-specific-index-in-the-1000-dimensional-output-tensor-in), has been asked about a human-readable label associated with the index and an answer pointed to an index-to-label mapping available in this URL: https://gist.github.com/maraoz/388eddec39d60c6d52d4

From the human readable label I suppose it is possible to find the Wordnet synset identifier via the label-to-synset mapping on this page: http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2015/browse-synsets but I am wondering whether this is already done?

Answer (score 0):

The mapping seems to be straightforward with the data from https://gist.github.com/maraoz/388eddec39d60c6d52d4 and http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2015/browse-synsets:

```
{0: {'id': '01440764-n',
     'label': 'tench, Tinca tinca',
     'uri': 'http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn30/01440764-n'},
 1: {'id': '01443537-n',
     'label': 'goldfish, Carassius auratus',
     'uri': 'http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn30/01443537-n'},
 2: {'id': '01484850-n',
     'label': 'great white shark, white shark, man-eater, man-eating shark, Carcharodon carcharias',
    'uri': 'http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn30/01484850-n'},
 ...
```

See https://gist.github.com/fnielsen/4a5c94eaa6dcdf29b7a62d886f540372 for full file.

I have not checked thoroughly whether this mapping is actually correct.

This mapping was constructed with:

```
import ast
from lxml import html
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url_index = ('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maraoz/'
             '388eddec39d60c6d52d4/raw/'
             '791d5b370e4e31a4e9058d49005be4888ca98472/gistfile1.txt')
url_synsets = "http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2014/browse-synsets"

index_to_label = ast.literal_eval(requests.get(url_index).content)
elements = html.fromstring(requests.get(url_synsets).content).xpath('//a')

label_to_synset = {}
for element in elements:
    href = element.attrib['href']
    if href.startswith('http://imagenet.stanford.edu/synset?wnid='):
        label_to_synset[element.text] = href[42:]

index_to_synset = {
    k: {
        'id': label_to_synset[v] + '-n',
        'label': v,
        'uri': "http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn30/{}-n".format(
            label_to_synset[v])
    }
    for k, v in index_to_label.items()}


pprint(index_to_synset)
```