# TensorFlow saved_model.pb cannot be loaded correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

I have downloaded a [model](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/efficientnet_v2_imagenet21k_ft1k_m/classification/2?tf-hub-format=compressed) from Hub. The archive contains TensorFlow 2 saved model and if decompressed shows a file named `saved_model.pb` and a `variables` folder that inside has 2 files `variables.data-00000-of-00001` and `variables.index`.

This model seems cannot be passed to `tf.keras.models.load_model()`
I have tried

```
my_model=tf.saved_model.load('extraction_path')
```

but the resulting `loaded_model` object seems it isn't a normal model object ready to be used with something like `my_model=model.predict(image)`and the [documentation section](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load) about the function isn't clear.

What is the proper procedure that should be used with this model format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me on Python 3.9:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

extraction_path = "imagenet_efficientnet_v2_imagenet21k_ft1k_m_classification_2/"
test_image_path = "test.png"
# loading model from path
model = tf.saved_model.load(extraction_path)

# load and reshaping input image
image_np = np.array(Image.open(test_image_path))
input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np, tf.float32)
input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]

# run detection on test image
detections = model(input_tensor)

print(detections.shape)
# TensorShape([1, 1000])
# prediction confidence for each of the 1000 classes in the imagenet dataset
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't crash but how the result classification labels should be accessed?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528905/get-imagenet-label-for-a-specific-index-in-the-1000-dimensional-output-tensor-in) should point you in the right direction. 
The labels are not contained in the model output. You will need to use some other dictionary that maps the indices in the output tensor of the model to the labels from the ImageNet dataset.

Comment: The extracted model archive should contain labels (maybe in files variables folder?) although documentation is lackluster about the way these should be accessed. The linked question uses tensorflow_hub library, it isn't clear how it works but shouldn't be needed.

Comment: From my experience, many TensorFlow models that have been pre-trained on popular open-source datasets (like ImageNet) don't contain mappings for the class labels. There are plenty of sources for the mapping online, [like this one](https://gist.github.com/yrevar/942d3a0ac09ec9e5eb3a)

Comment: Yes you are right. It doesn't include the labels as wrongly supposed. But how to read its signatures correctly?